# GCM manually unregister from google server not work

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i've a registered device from Google server and from myServer, if i manually unregister the device from Google server but not from myServer i keep getting the notification from myServer.
i call `GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);`
and after the call go to GCMIntentService into the method

```
@Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
            //ServerUtilities.customUnregister(context, registrationId);
        } else {
            // This callback results from the call to unregister made on
            // ServerUtilities when the registration to the server failed.
            Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring server unregister callback");
        }
    }
```

i've read this [developer.android how unRegistration works](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg) but it's no clear for me
why do i keep receiving notifications?
tnks for response

Answer (score 1):

After unregister gcm event u should unregister in your 3rd server side application.

```
 protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
            ServerUtilities.customUnregister(context, registrationId); // here 3rd server side unregister
        } else {
            // This callback results from the call to unregister made on
            // ServerUtilities when the registration to the server failed.
            Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring server unregister callback");
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i do not register on myServer although i deleted from the Google server will continue to receive notifications? there is no way? if so then i ask myself why call GCMRegistrar.unregister(context)?

Comment: yes.You should unregister from your server. Full Unregistration works only with 3rd server

Comment: You call unregister event from your client side - that GCMRegistrar.unregister(context) do

Comment: tnks,hoped functioned as in the case of uninstallation, but in this case will manage even if the call to the server goes to error!

Comment: I waited about 50 minutes and no longer receiving notifications from google without notice of cancellation to myServer, and in my server when i try to send a message google responds with a "NotRegistered". I try again if there is coincidence